# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tweensContainer' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Getting this error while using materialize tooltip. I'm showing tooltip on accordion collapse event and on page scroll event. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Without seeing any code to replicate the problem, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: So, what? should he had pasted the whole library code here? He gave ref to lib and what he was using that caused the error. If someone could helped why shouldn't that person be allowed?

Comment: I've seen a trend by of putting down new users by mediocre ones on this site. This was a fair question with good reference.